# How to solve a circuit network involving a resistor parallel to a voltage source using only nodal analysis?

Tags: dc, matrix, superposition, nodal-analysis

I have been stuck on this for the past week and this week i just dont seem to find out what am i doing wrong. Please help me spot my mistake. Here you can find  [My circuit on multisim](https://www.multisim.com/content/6KnJmavEpPdsEJvQLtGMfB/my-question/open/). Please provide me with as much details as you possibly can nothing you write will be considered redundant by any word and help is appreciated much.

[image: The question and my solution]

Comment: Hint: you don't need to solve for \$V_2\$.

Comment: Also, the strictly defined nodal analysis simply can't solve circuits containing voltage sources.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply @ThePhoton I know that the voltage at v2= E2=2v; However they want us to write in code in matlab later. so even given the fact that i know that the voltage at v2=2v  and the current across R3 is E2/R3 amp. I cant seem to figure out what happens when i have  a current source connected to ground from one side and to R2 from the other and how to calculate if we now have only two active nodes. Please more hints.

Comment: Ask a separate question. Current source is a different kettle of fish

Comment: SO... hint, answer for my original question anybody?

Comment: Remove R3......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a fourth node in your diagram, at the junction of E1 and R1. But that one and V2 have known voltages, so the problem reduces to just two unknowns. I get the following equation:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}+\frac{1}{R4} && -\frac{1}{R4} \\
 -\frac{1}{R4} && \frac{1}{R4}+\frac{1}{R5}+\frac{1}{R6}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 V1 \\
 V3
\end{bmatrix}
  =
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{E1}{R1}+\frac{E2}{R2} \\
 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This allows you to solve for V3, and once you know that, you can get \$I_x = \frac{V3}{R6}\$.

Comment: Exactly what I get. I might have first written down the nodal equations before going to matrices, but the OP went straight to the matrices. So looks good to me.

Comment: Its funny because that i have come to this solution since the first time i took a look at this question, but i seemed to get it wrong every time. now i know why. ITS MATLAB. I have managed to save values in variables and use them over and over again without changing the values that i had saved in them. Anyhow i cannot thank you enough. Thanks so much.